# Copy entire row to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that looks for new values in another worksheet and copies the new values to 1 row down my original worksheet, works perfectly, however, now, I need to change the code to copy not only the new found value (1 cell), but the entire row, I tried changing the code but I cannot get it to work, here is the code that copies only one cell:

```
 Dim Lastrow       As Long  'the last row in Sheet2 col E
   Dim iRow1         As Long  'the row number on Sheet1
   Dim Sh1           As Worksheet
   Dim Sh2           As Worksheet

   Set Sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("originalwkb")
 Set Sh1 = Workbooks("383839.xlsb").Sheets(3)

ThisWorkbook.Activate
   Lastrow = Sh2.Range("e65536").End(xlUp).Row

   iRow1 = 2

  ' Loop through values in column E of Sheet1


   Do
      Set FindCell = Sh2.Range("E2", Sh2.Cells(Lastrow, "E")).Find(What:=Sh1.Cells(iRow1, "E"), _
             After:=Sh2.Range("E2"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
      If FindCell Is Nothing Then
         'add to bottom of list
         Lastrow = Lastrow + 1
         Sh2.Cells(Lastrow, "E") = Sh1.Cells(iRow1, "E")
      End If
      iRow1 = iRow1 + 1
   Loop Until IsEmpty(Sh1.Cells(iRow1, "E"))
```

Comment: The entire row where a value is found or up to and including the last column in the row where values are present? Can there be blanks within the range to be copied?

Comment: If you have a set number of columns to copy next to found cell you could use resize method to capture adjacent cell values.

Comment: The entire row there a value is found, say, columns A:Z, (even though the value found was on column E), All columns in both sheets match (A:Z).

Comment: `sh2.Rows(Lastrow).Value = Sh1.Rows(iRow1).Value`

Comment: Scott Craner again got it just perfectly! He is really one of the best here! Thanks once again Scott!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the following line.

```
Sh2.Cells(Lastrow, "E") = Sh1.Cells(iRow1, "E")
```

To

```
Sh2.Rows(Lastrow).Value = Sh1.Rows(iRow1).Value
```

**EDIT**: Didn't see @Scott Craner reply since I do not read answers. Guess we can give him some credits for this answer :)

Comment: Perfect! Same as Scott´s answer. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @Roca Yeah didn't see his reply. I edited my post to give him some credit too.